# Derive Newton's Law of Gravitation from Kepler's 3rd Law, Assuming an Elliptical Orbit?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, astrophysics, velocity, astronomy

Can you derive Newton's law of gravitation from Kepler's third law, assuming an elliptical orbit?
Most of what I've seen have been people solving it with a circular orbit. However, I find it impossible for an elliptical orbit because the radius changes as one object orbits a bigger one.

I first tried work backward: deriving Kepler's law from Newton's. I ended with the fact there are two components to acceleration (the one working with or against the velocity and the centripetal one), which can be shown as this
$$
\vec{a} = v'\hat{T}+v^2κ\hat{N}
$$
v and v' stands for velocity and the derivative of velocity, T_hat is the unit tangent vector, κ is the curvature, and N_hat is the normal vector.

[image: Text]

I ended up with this
$$
-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{r} = m\vec{a}
$$
$$
-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat{r} = \vec{a}
$$
$$
-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat{r}=(v'\hat{T}+v^2κ\hat{N})
$$
Because the velocity does simply equal 2πr/T, like most examples use:
$$
\frac{GMm}{r^2} = m\frac{v^2}{r}
$$
I, again, don't see how one can derive Newton's law of gravitation from Kepler's 3rd law. I feel like I am missing something; are my understanding and reasoning wrong? or is there a way to derive it?

Comment: i think it should have been the other way round, to derive all kepler's three laws from F=GMm/r^2 is doable.

Comment: *Most of what I've seen have been people solving it with a circular orbit.* There are an infinite number of force laws that allow a circular orbit.

Comment: Yes you can, that’s how Newton figured it out. Check out Feynman’s lost lecture where he reproduces Newton’s geometrical arguments (with a slight modification)

Comment: @lpz Feyman's reconstruction is for a demonstration that Kepler's *first* law narrows down the possibilities to an inverse square law of gravity. However, this question enquires about starting from Kepler's *third* law.

Comment: yes sorry got them mixed up

Comment: I suspect a derivation must in one way or another (implicitly or explicitly) make use of the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector). This is a conserved vector quantity that guarantees the orbits close, and is only conserved for an inverse square law (orbits also close for a harmonic oscillator potential but I think the symmetry is different). For generic force laws, you can't get ellipses, because the orbits don't close, since there is no conserved quantity guaranteeing they do.

Comment: While [this question was not the same as yours](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576745/), my answer to it addresses how you can show that an elliptical orbit due to a central force must be due to an inverse-square force law.

Comment: See also [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564604/condition-for-force-acting-on-a-particle-for-it-to-move-in-a-hyperbola/564662) which does the same thing for a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

I start with quoting Kepler's third law, as stated in the Wikipedia article about [Keplers three laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion)

> The square of a planet's orbital period is proportional to the cube of the length of the semi-major axis of its orbit.

Here's the thing: when the orbit is eccentric the length of the semi-major axis is a particular *average* of perihelion and aphelion distances.

That is: in the way Kepler's third law is stated the orbit of the planet is mathematically *circularized*.

The way that the third law is stated does not use the actual orbit, the actual orbit is substituted with a circular orbit that has *the same total energy*.

So: to show that Kepler's third law narrows down the possibilities to an inverse square law of gravity: there is only one way to do that: you have to use circular orbits.